# How to get End Date, if start date and number of days are given in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I'am writing a function in laravel that calculates the end date given the start date and no. of days and stores it in the database.

This is what I have come up with:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
   {
        $it = new iternary;

        $it->StartDate = Input::get("StartDate");

        $it->NoPeople = Input::get("NoPeople");

        $it->NoDays = Input::get("NoDays");

        (int)$ttemp=$it->NoDays;

        $it->budget = Input::get("budget");

        $EndDate = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') + $it-
         >NoDays, date('Y')));

        $it->EndDate = $EndDate;

        $it->save();

        return view('success');

     }
```

But this gives me the wrong output.
It gives me end date same as start date.
Can you'll help please.
Thanks

Comment: Why not use the `Carbon` package which laravel comes with?

Comment: I'm just begining with laravel so not really sure of Carbon dates
Can you please demonstrate.

Comment: Given that you're completely ignoring your start date when you create your end date, it's no wonder it's wrong

Comment: @Crane1912 http://carbon.nesbot.com/ a lot of examples here.

Comment: @MarkBaker just realized that...thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
$startDate = new \Carbon\Carbon('2017-05-09')
$endDate = $startDate->addDays('10')
```

Further info about adding and subtracting in carbon can be found here [here](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub)

You can also use PHP's default DateTime class for modification,

```
$date = new DateTime('2017-05-09')
$date->modify('+ 10 days')
$date->modify('-1 month')
$date->modify('next year')
$date->modify('previous month')
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

I am not much aware about Carbon dates in laravel. But in PHP, you can try this:

```
$startDate = '2017-05-09';
$days = 3;
$dayStr = $days == 1 ? 'day' : 'days';

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+ '.$days. ' '.$dayStr, strtotime($startDate )));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/XNcuk)